# Getting Started with AngularJS and Material Design

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I am trying to play around with the Material Design stuff for AngularJS. The Project can be seen [here](https://material.angularjs.org/). I'm trying to do a basic project. This has led me to two questions about material design.

1. How do I use an icon for a button? I ran `git submodule update --init` per the docs. I have the icons directory. However, I do not understand how to actually use a button. For instance, I want to use the refresh icon (/icons/system_icons/av/res/2x_web/ic_loop_24dp.png), so I'm trying the following:

However, the icon is off-center. How should I fix this?

2. How do I setup navigation up in the app?

Thank you!